# Assemble: repeat block of code

Tags: assemble

Using [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble), how do I repeat (n)time a block of code {{> imageBox}} that is embedded into pages?

```
<div>
 {{> imageBox }} 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly iterate over an array of the desired size.  For example:

```
---
blocks:
 - one
 - two
 - three
---
Repeat blocks:
{{#each blocks}}
    <div>Block {{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

Results in

```
Repeat blocks
Block one
Block two
Block three
```

If you don't care about the values, you can just omit the `{{this}}` reference.